# C# Not displaying all objects in myarray?

Tags: c#

I have another class called Rectangles and I am iterating over the objects to add them into the list with a for loop. After that I am using a foreach loop to print all the data out at once. For some reason I am having to press enter each time to display the result.
This is my class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Rectangle
{
    public class Rectangles
    {
        int Length;
        int Width;

        // constructor
        public void CalcPerimiter(int Length, int Width)
        {
            int Perimiter = Length + Width;
            Console.WriteLine("The perimiter is   " + Perimiter);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public void CalcArea(int Length, int Width)
        {
            int Area = Length * Width;
            Console.WriteLine("The Area is   " + Area);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

This is my main

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Rectangle;
using System.Collections;

namespace Rectangle_calculation
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Rectangle.Rectangles[] First = new Rectangles[20];//Storing th 

            for (int i = 0; i < First.Length; i++)
            {
                First[i] = new Rectangles();
                First[i].CalcPerimiter(33, 45);
                First[i].CalcArea(22, 88);
                First[i].CalcPerimiter(23, 75);
                First[i].CalcArea(12, 55);
                First[i].CalcPerimiter(32, 25);
                First[i].CalcArea(220, 88);
                First[i].CalcPerimiter(239, 35);
                First[i].CalcArea(120, 15);
            }

            foreach (Rectangles rectangle in First)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(rectangle.ToString());
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The ReadLine method is designed to wait for you to press Enter.  See the [MSDN remarks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for details

Comment: Looks like you got a few good answers, please accept one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove Console.ReadLine(); from both methods of your Rectangles class  and also from your foreach(which is in main) loop

Answer (score 1):

`Console.ReadLine();` requiers the user to hit enter.  That's the pause you're seeing

Comment: I have tried removing it and still not doing what its supposed to

Comment: Where is it stopping (use the debugger to pause and see what line of code it's on when prompted for user input)

Answer (score 0):

remove `Console.ReadLine();` from your for loop

Comment: Cheers forgot about the ones in the class file

Answer (score 0):

Console.ReadLine() is the curlprit which is waiting for a key stroke after every line execution within the for loop.